# caffe.Net AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, git, caffe

I'm using the `Ubuntu 14.04` without `GPU` and i want to run this code ( with `CPU` only )  : https://github.com/xinleipan/py-faster-rcnn-with-new-dataset . 
I i do : `python ./tools/demo.py --cpu --net vgg16` he print this error :

```
    I0505 14:45:53.473182  7095 net.cpp:122] Setting up rpn_cls_prob_reshape
I0505 14:45:53.473208  7095 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 1 18 14 14 (3528)
I0505 14:45:53.473222  7095 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 117496524
I0505 14:45:53.473233  7095 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer proposal
I0505 14:45:53.515135  7095 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer proposal
I0505 14:45:53.515180  7095 net.cpp:406] proposal <- rpn_cls_prob_reshape
I0505 14:45:53.515198  7095 net.cpp:406] proposal <- rpn_bbox_pred
I0505 14:45:53.515211  7095 net.cpp:406] proposal <- im_info
I0505 14:45:53.515228  7095 net.cpp:380] proposal -> rois
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/demo.py", line 134, in <module>
    net = caffe.Net(prototxt, caffemodel, caffe.TEST)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

how resolved this

Comment: This post doesn't show any research effort. if you looked inside the python file you would see you have to just use `--cpu`.

Comment: an other problem :
`File "./tools/demo.py", line 134, in <module>
    net = caffe.Net(prototxt, caffemodel, caffe.TEST)`

Comment: You need to post the whole error message. No one will be able to infer it automatically.

Comment: ok i'm changing the title

Comment: Are you using the same caffe version from that repo or another?

Comment: emmm if no ???!!

Answer (score 0):

This [PR](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/issues/249) says the issue is with the caffe version mismatch. Just comment the following line

```
self_.attr("phase") = static_cast(this->phase_);
```

in `include/layers/python_layer.hpp` in caffe.